# How would I apply a moving gradient across several objects

Tags: animation, color

What I am interested in doing is taking a color gradient and applying across several objects.[image]

This image is the best idea that I have to recreate what I am looking for.  For an example say that the circles at the bottom are actually cylinders spread out across a plane.  What I want to do is apply the gradient at the top across the cylinders.

To take it a step further, is it possible to animate the gradient to create a "breathing" type effect that shows up on the cylinders?

Answer (score 2):

Add an empty, use this shader setup here for all nodes:

[image]

you can even animate the colors now via the empty:

[image]

of course you can use the x and z values as well, if you want to. Depending on the rotation/position of your object, you might have to take another axis and multiply/add values, than i did.

Comment: +1.. Not totally clear from the post ..but is OP's reference  a radial gradient? .. (Maybe need a _Length_ in there)..

Comment: you are right - waiting for him to clear that up.